# How to add changes for NO ENCRYPT DB2 option to db2RestoreStruct

Tags: db2, restore

I am trying to restore encrypted DB to non-encryped DB. I made changes by setting piDbEncOpts to SQL_ENCRYPT_DB_NO but still restore is being failed. Is there db2 sample code is there where I can check how to set "NO Encrypt" option in DB2. I am adding with below code snippet.

db2RestoreStruct->piDbEncOpts->encryptDb = SQL_ENCRYPT_DB_NO

Comment: Please provide more details, e.g., which version and platform, how the database was encrypted, how you run the command, etc.

Comment: take a look: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-can-i-decrypt-encrypted-db2-database you need to add "NO ENCRYPT" option to you restore command

Comment: @data_henrik, I am running a command through C code that takes backup of the encrypted database. I can create an encrypted database through "db2 create db mydb encrypt". I can also restore through the command line but whenever I am doing restore through db2 's restore API, it got failed. I am using linux RHEL 7 and DB2 version is 11.5. I am looking for an option from db2 API to restore the encrypted database to non-encrypted.

Comment: @mshabou, Thanks! I can do it through the command line but I am looking for option from db2 API to restore the encrypted database to non-encrypted where I might need to use restore API https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=apis-db2restore-restore-database-table-space .

Comment: @CPPDevelop  please edit your question to show your 'C' code in particular how you initialize the `sqleDbEncryptionOptions` structure as pointed to from the `db2RestoreStruct` structure. Learn now to properly ask a question by giving all relevant facts. Otherwise your question will get closed for lack of detail.

Comment: @CPPDevelop , it would be helpful if you would properly ( i.e. fully ) show your code, as your single line update is ambiguous. If both structs are on the stack,  try `  restoreStruct.piDbEncOpts = & sqleDbEncryptionOptions;
  restoreStruct.piDbEncOpts->encryptDb = SQL_ENCRYPT_DB_NO ;`

Comment: Yes, I can not add more code. My only doubt is that by setting options like piDbEncOpts->encryptDb = SQL_ENCRYPT_DB_NO should work for restore of  encrypted database to non encrypted database through restore API or is there any way of adding C code except setting of SQL_ENCRYPT_DB_NO?

Answer (score 0):

The 'C' API named `db2Restore` will restore an encrypted-image to a unencrypted database , when used correctly.

You can use a modified version of IBM's samples files: `dbrestore.sqc` and related files, to see how to do it.

Depending on your 'C' compiler version and settings you might get a lot of warnings from IBM's code, because IBM does not appear to maintain the code of their samples as the years pass. However, you do not need to run IBM's sample code, you can study it to understand how to fix your own C code.

If installed, the samples component must match your Db2-server version+fixpack , and you must use the C include files that come with your Db2-server version+fixpack to get the relevant definitions.

The modifications to IBM's samples code include:

- When using the db2Restore API ensure its first argument has a value that is compatible with your server Db2-version-and-fixpack to access the required functionality. If you specify the wrong version number for the first argument, for example a version of Db2 that did not support this functionality, then the API will fail. For example, on my Db2-LUW v11.1.4.6, I used the predefined `db2Version1113` , like this:
   `db2Restore(db2Version1113, &restoreStruct, &sqlca);`
- When setting the restore `iOptions` field: enable the flag `DB2RESTORE_NOENCRYPT`, for example, in IBM's example, include the additional flag: `restoreStruct.iOptions = DB2RESTORE_OFFLINE | DB2RESTORE_DB | DB2RESTORE_NODATALINK | DB2RESTORE_NOROLLFWD | DB2RESTORE_NOENCRYPT;`
- Ensure the restoredDbAlias differs from the encrypted-backup alias name.

I tested with Db2 v11.1.4.6 (db2Version1113 in the API) with gcc 9.3.

I also tested with Db2 v11.5 (db2Version11500 in the API) with gcc 9.3.